# Django StdImage won't work when using a proxy model

Tags: django, django-models

In Django i have a model that represents an image with a description that has Foreign Key to another model, this model uses an StdImageField to save the image and auto create a thumbnail. This model also has a choice field with two options representing the type of image.

In my admin i show this model as an inline of the main model, however i'd like to show this model as two separate inlines in the admin as if they were two separate types of objects to the user, for this i'm using 2 proxy models and registering them instead.

The problem is that when i use this proxy models the StdImageField wont resize the uploaded image nor create a thumbnail. I believe this is due to the issue described [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-stdimage/issues/detail?id=44)

My code is the following (stripped down for the purpose):

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from stdimage import StdImageField

class MainModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    SOME_MODEL_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            ('t1','Type 1'),
            ('t2','Type 2'),
    )
    main_model = models.ForeignKey(to='MainModel')
    pic = StdImageField(upload_to='img', size =(200,200), thumbnail_size = (100,100))
    pic_type = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = SOME_MODEL_TYPE_CHOICES)


class SomeModelT1Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SomeModelT1Manager, self).get_query_set().filter(pic_type='t1')

class SomeModelT1(SomeModel):
    objects = SomeModelT1Manager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.pic_type = 't1'
        super(SomeModelT1, self).save(*args,**kwargs)

class SomeModelT2Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SomeModelT2Manager, self).get_query_set().filter(pic_type = 't2')

class SomeModelT2(SomeModel):
    objects = SomeModelT2Manager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.pic_type = 't2'

        super(SomeModelT2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

## admin.py

from django.contrib

```
import admin
from test_app.models import *

class SomeModelT1Inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SomeModelT1
    exclude = ('pic_type',)

class SomeModelT2Inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SomeModelT2
    exclude = ('pic_type',)

class MainModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
            SomeModelT1Inline,
            SomeModelT2Inline
            ]

admin.site.register(MainModel, MainModelAdmin)
```

So my question is wheter there is another way of doing this or how do i correct this issue in stdimage. I think the problem could be that `contribute_to_class` never gets called in StdImageField when in the Proxy context, mainly because  `__metaclass__` is not set to `models.SubfieldBase` as explained in the [django documentation for custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass)

However that's only a wild guess as django's FileField or ImageField don't set that either.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess without any debugging: The `StdImageField`'s `contribute_to_class` method registers some signal listeners for the orginal `SomeModel` for `post_init` and `post_save`. These handlers don't get called if the `sender` is a proxy model.

One a bit hackish way around this could be making your own signal receivers for the proxy models that send out the `post_save` and `post_init` signals with `SomeModel` as sender..

EDIT: You could try putting this at the end of your `models.py`; it's quite a hack and probably cause some errors if you would have to register different handlers for the original model and the proxy models...

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_init
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=SomeModelT1)
def post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    post_save.send(sender=SomeModel, instance=instance, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_init, sender=SomeModelT1)
def post_init_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    post_init.send(sender=SomeModel, instance=instance, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Not working, the send method won't let me include an instance parameter and the receiver decorator needs a kwargs argument.

Comment: Sorry, can't try it right now, edited it again, maybe working now :)

Comment: Not working, something about a method receiving two signal parameteres